# Starting the algorand sandbox but the error "the input device is not a TTY" comes up?

Tags: blockchain, sandbox, tty, winpty, algorand

I'm trying to setup the alogrand development environment using the algorand sandbox, when I start the sandbox using the git bash and the command `./sandbox up` the following error comes up:

[image: The error screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue with this on https://github.com/algorand/sandbox/issues/115

In short currently, your best bet is to use WSL 2 rather than Git Bash.
This is a bit more complex to set up but gives you an environment closer to Linux.
See https://github.com/algorand/sandbox#option-1-using-wsl-2 for details on how to use WSL 2.

Comment: Thanks, the issue was with the docker compose command. I solved it by adding winpty prefix to the docker compose command in the sandbox file